# structfun with vector input

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, histogram

I have a struct : many(i).fincomp, each one of these is (200x1)
I want to create a histogram count for each 'i':
histc(many(i).fincomp,1:12) <-this works

```
>>histmany = structfun(@(x)histc(x.fincomp,1:12),many, 'UniformOutput', false); 
Error using structfun 
Inputs to STRUCTFUN must be scalar structures.
```

what am I doing wrong?

I tried with arrayfun as well

note: some of the data is NaN, the rest is numbers

Thanks

Comment: whoops apparently it didn't work when I used arrayfun because I wrote `'false'` instead of `false`:`histmany = arrayfun(@(x)histc(x.fincomp,1:12),many, 'UniformOutput', false);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `structfun` since `many` is not a struct. Use `arrayfun` or `cellfun`.

Answer (score 1):

You could forgo the ARRAYFUN loop altogether, by converting the array-of-struct to a matrix. HISTC can operate on matrices (works along the first non-singleton dimension, namely columns here):

```
histmany = histc(horzcat(many.fincomp), 1:12);
```

I used this simple example to test it:

```
many = struct();
for i=1:10
    many(i).fincomp = randn(200,1);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If `fincomp` field contains same size column vector, you can get all the fields into a matrix:

```
data = [many.fincomp];

histc(data);
```